# get user properties in result of IQ xmpp stanza

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, openfire, ejabberd-hooks, ejabberd-api

I am creating XMPP users using OpenFire [create-user](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/restapi/readme.html#create-a-user) RestAPI call. And i am setting some properties for users as indicated in [PayLoad Example 2](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/restapi/readme.html#create-a-user).

After creating users, i add them to each others rosters. So, every user has every other user in his/her contact list (roster)

Now, on the client side (i use smack library), when i retrieve the roster for any user, i expect the properties to come back as well along with the users' jabber id and such. But i am not seeing the properties xml tag.

I don't want to create vCards (as i have heard it's hard to set up LDAP with OpenFire, etc) just to achieve this lightweight metadata setting for the user.

Any idea if what i am trying to do is even feasible. Are properties supposed to be transmitted in the **IQ result stanza** in response to the **IQ GET stanza**?

Thanks for looking and thanks in advance.

**PS:** *If vCard is the only way for me to achieve what i want, then pls let me know how to go about setting it up. Any pointers are highly appreciated.*

Comment: if you send a GET iq, openfire wainting for a Result or an Error reply IQ,

Comment: I get a result iq back from openfire but there is no properties tag. I am using wireshark to monitor the xmpp traffic on the network.

Comment: Can't help about it. As i Know, Rest API are an old project deprecated, but I can be wrong; anyway I never used as plugin so I don't know specific usecase.

Comment: thanks @MrPk. do you know of any tool that i can use to send stanzas (iq, presence, message, etc) to the server? I don't want to use PostMan or jMeter and such heavy clients since i can't send raw stanzas. do you know of any lightweight command line interface (preferably with support to MAC OSX)

Comment: Spark Client allows to send raw packet to your server (it's not really "lightweight" but maybe helps)